# Select all rows that have the same value in two columns, while simultaneously having different values in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where caretaker visits are recorded. The table contains `caretakerCode`, `patientID`, `visitDate` and `visitAddress`.

I need to show all information from rows where the same caretaker went to more than one patient on the same day. Here is an example.

```
caretakerCode      patientID     visitDate      visitAddress
---------------------------------------------------------------
 John Q               13         2022/01/13     27 Hamilton Rd
 John Q               13         2022/01/14     27 Hamilton Rd
 John Q               15         2022/01/14     101 Congress St
 Melanie B            22         2022/01/15     3 Redroad Ct
```

In the example, the output would be

```
caretakerCode      patientID     visitDate      visitAddress
---------------------------------------------------------------
   John Q             13         2022/01/14     27 Hamilton Rd
   John Q             15         2022/01/15     101 Congress St
```

I have tried joins but I'm not sure how to make it take more than 2 columns. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the `JOIN` attempts you've tried already so we have a starting point of where to help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your example is wrong, since you wanted to achieve to show the visits on the same day. Your example shows 2 different days: 2022/01/14 and 2022/01/15.

Assume the table name is dbo.tVisits.

#### Create test table

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE dbo.tVisits
(
    caretakerCode nvarchar(50)  NOT NULL,
    patientID     int           NOT NULL,
    visitDate     date          NOT NULL,
    visitAddress  nvarchar(512) NOT NULL
);
```

#### Insert test data

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tVisits
(
    caretakerCode,
    patientID,
    visitDate,
    visitAddress
)
VALUES
( N'John Q',    13, '20220113', N'27 Hamilton Rd'  ),
( N'John Q',    13, '20220114', N'27 Hamilton Rd'  ),
( N'John Q',    15, '20220114', N'101 Congress St' ),
( N'Melanie B', 22, '20220115', N'3 Redroad Ct'    );
```

#### Execute query

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        V.caretakerCode,
        V.visitDate
    FROM dbo.tVisits V
    GROUP BY 
        V.caretakerCode,
        V.visitDate
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT 
    V.caretakerCode,
    V.patientID,
    V.visitDate,
    V.visitAddress
FROM dbo.tVisits V
INNER JOIN CTE ON 
    CTE.caretakerCode = V.caretakerCode
    AND CTE.visitDate = V.visitDate
ORDER BY 1,3,2;
```

#### Returned rows

| caretakerCode | patientID | visitDate | visitAddress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Q | 13 | 2022-01-14 | 27 Hamilton Rd |
| John Q | 15 | 2022-01-14 | 101 Congress St |

#### Cleanup

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.tVisits;
```

Explanation:
In the [Common Table Expression CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) you select rows where the same caretaker has multiple rows at the same visit date.
In the 2nd step you use this information on the original table to filter the rows by inner join.

Comment: Why to add a note that this code is untested instead of testing it before answering?

Comment: @JonasMetzler I enhanced my answer based on your suggestion.